# Atom - alignment of comments

Tags: python, atom-editor

I write Python in Atom. Are there any packages or hotkeys that I can use to align the comments like this:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,                # the df containing the data
                            source='u',        # first element of the dyad
                            target='v',        # second element of the dyad
                            edge_attr='weight')# weight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own keymap in Atom. You can paste this code:

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-cmd-]': 'editor:auto-indent'
```

This will create a keymap, where when you press `ctrl+cmd+j` it will indent automatically.

> Note: The above will work in macOS. For windows or linux, you need to change `cmd`.